# tag helper [asp-for] for the input doesn't work with byte's array values (opposite to @Html.HiddenFor)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

When `@Html.HiddenFor(e=>e.RowVersion)` works well and generates:

```
<input id="RowVersion" name="RowVersion" type="hidden" value="AAAAAAAARlI=" />
```

But the tag helper version `<input asp-for="@Model.RowVersion" name="RowVersion" hidden />` generates:

```
<input name="RowVersion" hidden id="RowVersion" value="System.Byte[]" />
```

Problem there is crazy value "System.Byte[]".

I want to keep using tag helper version for consistency. How I can enable bytes array serialization?

Comment: Is `RowVersion` a byte array?

Comment: Yes it is. RowVersion is a byte array https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency

Comment: I must be in some special state of code-blind oblivion to read your question and then ask what I just asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `type="hidden"` instead of `hidden` attribute!

You should be able to achieve the same thing if you do

```
/*
 *   From the ViewModel:
 *       byte[] RowVersion = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("FR")
 */
<input asp-for="RowVersion" type="hidden" />
```

#### Comparison

[image]
[image]

#### The reason (I am not 100% sure though)

Tag helper `asp-for` will try to generate the type for the HTML input based on the property type the tag helper binds to, when you don't specify a `type` attribute on the HTML input. If it can't find a proper type for the HTML input, it would default to `type="text"`.

That's why your `<input asp-for="RowVersion" hidden />` will generate a hidden textbox. Tag helper doesn't sanitize the input value when generating textbox:

[image]

But if you specify `type="hidden"` and your property type is `byte[]`, it will actually do the Base64 encoding for you:

[image]

That's why `@Html.HiddenFor()` as well as `<input type="hidden" asp-for= />` worked but the others didn't!

Comment: Thank you. Next question: WHY THIS WORKS?

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Next time I will be prepared to experiment with type attribute.

Comment: This isn't an ASP.NET quirk. The [default input type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#input_types) is `text` while  [hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) is a global attribute that applies to every HTML element. All browsers will treat `<input hidden id='RowVersion' />` as `<input type="text" hidden id='RowVersion' />`.